# Is PackageMaker considered the standard for Mac OS X software installation? Or is there something else out there?

Tags: macos, installation, packagemaker

I've put together my very first package with PackageMaker (for a system service), but I am not happy about several faults:

- Frequent crashes while applying target permissions to my source files
- Package source files are not automatically or easily refreshed
- File filter does not work

Is there something else out there more capable of this task?  Free is not a requirement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is, and yes it's buggy. Apple uses the command line version pretty much exclusively so the GUI tends to have the feeling that it's been slapped together by a summer intern and never tested.

Comment: It is really good to hear that it is not just me.  *"it's been slapped together by a summer intern and never tested"*  Exactly!

Comment: Good guess, you are right, PackageMaker was maintained by summer interns. I knew one of them ... That I kinda wanted to hurt him goes without saying ;)

Answer (score 2):

PackageMaker is the standard, for things that need an installer (many regular applications just use a DMG, often with a background image telling the user to copy the bundle to /Applications - eg Firefox does this)

MindVision VISE is a commercial solution you can look at, used by some people, but personally I think the look & feel of the resulting installers is subtly wrong (and slightly retro) - that's a subjective viewpoint of course.

Package Maker works pretty well for many people - though documentation is rather scant; are you sure the problems you're experiencing aren't fixable?

Comment: The situation has  gotten worse: It cannot run scripts on Snow Leopard during the installation, which I require.  (I've another question here on SO about that.) So, at this point, *no*, I can't live with PackageManager as is.

Comment: PackageMaker (or really, Installer.app) certainly *can* run scripts on Snow Leopard during the installation - it's a standard feature. Is there something unusual about your setup that might be affecting the results you're getting?

Comment: Yes and no.  To ensure that it was not what my package was doing, I made a simple test case: I created a fresh package, had it install a static file to Documents, and had it run a script that consisted only of "touch /Users/stu/hi.txt".  It installed file file yet the script did not run.  It's been a few weeks since I did this, I will revisit.  Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There (now) is a great free alternative to PackageMaker with the simple name "Packages":
http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html

It's really easy to use, very stable and mature and even open source (in case you need to hack anything). Plus: it has a well written documentation!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem until I added `#!/bin/sh` at the top of the script. Apparently PackageMaker needs it; I wish the log was a bit more clear about it.

IHIH, Oren

Answer (score 0):

Since Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard it is recommended to use [pkgbuild and productbuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487596/making-os-x-installer-packages-like-a-pro-xcode4-developer-id-mountain-lion-re/11487658#11487658) instead of PackageMaker.