# Choices in packagemaker

Tags: macos, packagemaker

I'm currently making an installer with packagemaker.

I've created my project and I created multiple choices.
Choice 1 always needs to be installed but there also needs to be chosen between 6 other choices.

So I would like to configure that you can only click "Continue" when 2 choices are active.

If i place the payload of choice 1 in all the other payloads, the package will be very big. Maybe you know a requirement that if 1 other choice is checked, choice 1 will be checked automaticaly? I've tried everything this weekend but I can't find the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PackageMaker is deprecated. From own experience I can only recommend to [use the new tools pkgbuild, productbuild, and pkgutil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487596/making-os-x-installer-packages-like-a-pro-xcode4-developer-id-mountain-lion-re).

I recommend to take a look at iTunes Installers Distribution.xml, that should give you a glue on how to do dependencies,

Answer (score 1):

From your description, it seems that there is a choice that could be hidden to the end-user. So a possible solution would be to:

- make the Choice 1 invisible and then create a dependency on the state of this choice to the 6 other visible choices.

This can be achieved easily with another alternative to PackageMaker: [Packages](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html)

Comment: please elaborate bit more or share any links to do the above