# Pass Arguments to Package Maker Contents Install Destination from Command line (Terminal)

Tags: macos, command-line, osx-mountain-lion, packagemaker

I am using Mac 10.8 and latest version of Package Maker. My product destination path (Install Location) contains our Product version.

`Eg. Test/1.1.0.1/Sample.`

We have planned to automate the process. We will increase the build number in each automation. So I need to change the Version number in destination path in every automation. I am using below command to make the Packages using Terminal.

```
PackageMaker –v –d Test.pmdoc –o TestSample.pkg
```

Is there any option to pass the version number from this argument? Shall we implement this using a preinstall script? Please provide same samples if any option from Preinstall Scripts, since I am new to shell scripts. Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I found it much easier to do this:

- copy the package folder from a common location (ie /project-redist-master)
- modify package contents as desired (see below)
- create package

If you need more personalization, for example the version number somewhere *inside* the package, I found it most convenient to simple search & replace strings. For example you could write `___PROJECTVERSION___` to any text or resource file (ie pmdoc) where the version number is used. Then, before creating the package, run a little tool (bash script, personally I prefer writing Cocoa command line tools) that searches and replaces such placeholder strings. That tool would also get the version string from somewhere, for example a version.h header or the changelist number from source control.

Answer (score 0):

PackageMaker always was buggy has hell, and got deprecated with Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard.

I recommend to use [pkgbuild together with productbuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487596/making-os-x-installer-packages-like-a-pro-xcode4-developer-id-mountain-lion-re/11487658#11487658).