# productbuild --distribution : package xxx.pkg could not be loaded

Tags: java, macos, app-store, productbuild, pkg-file

I'm trying to package an application using the productbuild command to create a pkg file that will hold a license file. Here's how I'm doing it:

```
# Creates the first package  
productbuild --sign "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: Tamaggo" --component tamaggo\ ibi.app /Applications/ tamaggoibi.pkg

# Creates a package that will hold the first one using a distribution file
productbuild --distribution tamaggo\ ibi.app/Contents/distribution.xml --package-path . --sign "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: Tamaggo" bassel.pkg
```

I'm always getting the following warning:

**productbuild: warning: package ./tamaggoibi.pkg could not be loaded**

If i double-click on the first created package the installation completes successfully. If I double click on the other, nothing happen.

I just can't figure out what's wrong with the first package that makes it not loadable.

Here's the distribution.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN""http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<installer-gui-script minSpecVersion="1">
<title>tamaggo ibi</title>
<license file="license.html" />
<background file="ApplicationBackground.gif" />
<options customize="never" allow-external-scripts="no"/>
<choices-outline>
    <line choice="choice0"/>
</choices-outline>

<choice id="choice0" title="Install tamaggo ibi">
    <pkg-ref id="tamaggoibi" />
</choice>

<pkg-ref id="tamaggoibi" version="1.6">#tamaggoibi.pkg</pkg-ref>
</installer-gui-script>
```

Comment: Ok, I just figure out that the first build has to be created using pkgbuild command... now it install the application correctly. The problem is that I still don't see my license file...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using pkgbuild fixed my original problem and I found this really good [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487596/making-os-x-installer-packages-like-a-pro-xcode4-developer-id-mountain-lion-re/11487658#11487658) that helped me to add the license to the installer.