# How to create Mac OS X app installer

Tags: macos, macros

I have a project in XCode (version 4.6.2) which include application and command line utility. How can I create a installer for that project to test if everything works (e.g. command line utility is installed in the /usr/local/bin directory and application in the /Applications directory)?

When I make a Archive Build from XCode and Distribute then I get a directory which has a proper directories structure and my compiled apps but I don't know how to do now an installer from that files.

Comment: It depends on what the command line utility does, but on OS X it's generally more common to package the CL utility within the app itself (in Resources or the like), then prompt the user to create a symlink the first time they open the app.

Comment: This is my first project for mac os x, so could you give me more info how can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

use [packagemaker (link invalid)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/packagemaker.1.html) ([distribution](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Porting/Conceptual/PortingUnix/distributing/distibuting.html)).

> packagemaker allows you to package files in a way that makes it easy
>   for end users to install them on
>        their computers.

Comment: I use Mountain Lion and XCode 4.6.2 and there is no packagemaker there.

Comment: [Packagemaker for mountain lion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4244495?start=0&tstart=0)

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487596/making-os-x-installer-packages-like-a-pro-xcode4-developer-id-mountain-lion-re

Comment: I tried to use pkgbuild but I couldn't run it on my command line utility because this is not a directory, only c++ compiled program.

Comment: Is not packagemaker deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

Log into your Apple Account and go to https://developer.apple.com/downloads/

Under Aug 7, 2012 you find the Auxiliary Tools which contains PackageManager among other tools