# Cocoa OS X - App Installer

Tags: macos, cocoa, installation

I want to make my application installer (.pkg). I didn't find any Apple documentation, but I know it's possible to make.

[image: Installer icon]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at PackageMaker. You can find it in 'Auxiliary Tools for Xcode' on apple downloads page. There are lot of tutorials in internet. There also was a doc on apple site, but I can't find it right now. You can also use [packagemaker](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/packagemaker.1.html) in terminal (thats how I create packages).

Also take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487596/making-os-x-installer-packages-like-a-pro-xcode4-developer-id-mountain-lion-re). You can find some interesting info there.