# Making OS X Installer Packages from Mountain Lion to Lion or Snow leopard

Tags: macos, packaging, pkgbuild, productbuild

I'm packaging my Mac app following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487596/making-os-x-installer-packages-like-a-pro-xcode4-developer-id-mountain-lion-re/11487658#11487658) tutorial.

The packages is generated in two steps:

1. First I generate a temporary package with `pkgbuild`. It contains just the binaries

   ```
   pkgbuild --root ${ROOT} --scripts ${SCRIPTS} --identifier myapp \
            --version ${VERSION} --install-location ${INSTALL_DIR} %PKG%
   ```

   where `%PKG%` is the temporary package file name in `Distribution.xml`.
2. Then I generate a package with the previous tmp package, a `Distribution.xml`, background image etc with `productbuild`:

   ```
   productbuild --distribution ${DIST_FILE} --package-path ${PKG_PATH} \
                --resources ${RESOURCES} ~/myapp.pkg'
   ```

`Distribution.xml` looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<installer-gui-script minSpecVersion="1">
    <title>MyApp</title>
    <options hostArchitectures="x86_64"/>
    <options customize="never" rootVolumeOnly="true"/>
    <welcome file="Welcome.rtf"/>
    <license file="license.rtf"/>
    <background file="background.png" scaling="proportional" alignment="bottomleft"/>
    <os-version min="10.6.6"/>
    <options customize="never" require-scripts="false"/>
    <product id="myapp" version="%VERSION%" />
    <choices-outline>
        <line choice="default">
            <line choice="myapp"/>
        </line>
    </choices-outline>
    <choice id="default"/>
    <choice id="myapp" visible="false">
        <pkg-ref id="myapp"/>
    </choice>
    <pkg-ref id="myapp" version="%VERSION%" onConclusion="none">%PKG%</pkg-ref>
</installer-gui-script>
```

The package works fine if it's executed on a machine with same OS version as the one it was created on - Mountain Lion in this case - but it throws a "cannot be installed in this computer" error in a earlier versions; log shows "Installation checks failed." message.

However, the temporary package installation works perfectly well, both on Lion and Snow Leopard. Somehow `productbuild` is restricting where the app can be installed. I've tried setting  in `Distribution.xml` but the result is the same.

Comment: I also needed to include plugins that worked in PackageMaker - simply add the "--plugins <path>" option to productbuild command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<os-version>` element needs to be nested within `<allowed-os-versions>`:

```xml
<allowed-os-versions>
    <os-version min="10.6.6" />
</allowed-os-versions>
```

You should also set `minSpecVersion="2"` in `<installer-gui-script>`.

See [Distribution Definition XML Schema Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/DistributionDefinitionRef/Chapters/Distribution_XML_Ref.html).

Comment: Removing     <options hostArchitectures="x86_64"/> did the trick. I thought snow leopard was 64 bits

Comment: @hithwen: Snow Leopard *is* 64 bits, [you probably just didn't boot it into the 64 bit mode](http://macperformanceguide.com/SnowLeopard-64bit.html).

Comment: Yes, I found exactly that. Looking at Activity monitor it seems that kernel_task is almost the only process not running in 64 bit, all these years w/o realizing... thanks a lot