# How to make .pkg(dot pkg) downloadable?

Tags: macos, apache, webserver, pkg-file

I have installed Apache Web server & hosted(or uploaded) a .pkg file on it.

Everything is working on server side. I can see directories browser to get

From the server, i can download zip, txt, doc. etc other files, but i am unable to download .pkg(dot pkg). From the browser, .pkg file is actually looks like a folder.

I have on many servers, e.g., SourceForge.net and i have downloaded [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/macpkg/) package. Its downloadable.

So, my question is how to make .pkg file directly downloadable. 
1. Is it some setting from my Apache server or
2. Need to create pkg of some other type?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're missing the mime type for a pkg file.

You'll need to find the mime type config - on an OSX box I have, it's in `/private/etc/apache2/mime.types`

Add the line

`application/x-newton-compatible-pkg                  pkg`

to that file and restart Apache

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer: yes you need to recreate the package by other way.

In `OS X` there are 4 main types of packages which you can install/distribute:

1. `.pkg` packages
2. `.mpkg` packages
3. `.app` bundles
4. `.dmg` drives

Further more `.pkg/.mpkg` packages have 2 more types flat and non flat packages.

- Flat Packages are single file packages.
- Non Flat Packages looks like a folder.

**Your problem is that your package is a non Flat package**. You can [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11487658/1578528) post to create a Flat package.