# Any OS X Installer(s) out there, similar to Inno Setup (preferably free)?

Tags: macos, inno-setup, setup-deployment

The title pretty much sums what I am looking for - will consider commercial solutions as well. Far from versed in the whole OS X "ecosystem" - therefore, any "tips" on this subject,  appreciated.

Cross-platform compatibility not a requirement.

Thank you.

Comment: Try to ask this rather on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/. [downvote is not mine]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old way was to use Apple's PackageMaker app.  It's been deprecated in Xcode 5 however.  You can still find it on Apple's Developer site -- I believe it's included in the Auxiliary Tools package ([more info](https://discussions.apple.com/message/24195633#24195633)).  Personally, I still use it for production releases.  Yes, it's scriptable.

The new way is to use `pkgbuild`, `productbuild`, and the other tools included in Xcode 5.  More info here:

[Making OS X Installer Packages like a Pro - Xcode Developer ID ready pkg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487596/making-os-x-installer-packages-like-a-pro-xcode4-developer-id-mountain-lion-re)

Comment: Thank you for taking time to respond. Do I understand correctly that I am bound to Apple's offering, then?

Comment: @elderelder Take a look at the last second answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487596/making-os-x-installer-packages-like-a-pro-xcode4-developer-id-mountain-lion-re).  I've never used it, but it look neat and has quite a few votes.  It's the only non-Apple installer option I've heard of.

Comment: Saw it in the mean time. Again, I appreciate your effort.