# How can I create a daemon/launch-agent/background application for OSX?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, xcode5, launchd

I'm not exactly sure what I'm looking for qualifies as... an agent,daemon, or just a small background application that runs with no GUI.

I have a small obj-c program I have written that runs in the Terminal. It needs to constantly check for values in a database and makes about 2 calls a second. I already have it working, I'm just not sure how to build this thing for release...

Ideally, I would like users to be able to install it like a regular Mac application but I'm not sure if this is possible. I am looking for something similar to the way Dropbox runs in the background and notifies the user of a new file, or how LogMeIn has something that runs in the background, or I also have an application called Aurora that has a background process called "Aurora Wakeup Helper". These are examples of what I am trying to imitate with this small obj-c program.

How would I build this for release in Xcode 5?

Answer (score 6):

To run your app as daemon or agent you should create a .plist file and put it to `/Library/LaunchDaemons` or `/Library/LaunchAgents`.
Example .plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.example.daemon</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/path/to/me/daemon</string>
        <string>-flag1</string>
        <string>-flag2</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>SessionCreate</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>mrDaemonUser</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

You could find more info in [Daemons and Services Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW7-BCIEDDBJ).

To install your app on user machine you should create an Installer package and write some scripts to put your files in a right place on user's system. For more info see this thread: [Making OS X Installer Packages like a Pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487596/making-os-x-installer-packages-like-a-pro-xcode4-developer-id-mountain-lion-re).

Comment: Awesome. So what is with `<string>-flag1</string>
        <string>-flag2</string>` ? Is one of the `ProgramArguments` the path to the program itself?

Comment: Yes, the first section `<string>/path/to/me/daemon</string>` is that path and also you could specify a command line arguments.

Comment: I created this Plist But How I can put here?? I am getting error : 
 

    open on /System/Library/LaunchAgents/MYservice.plist: Operation not permitted
    [SwiftyPlistManager] Unable to copy file. ERROR: “MYservice.plist” couldn’t be copied because you don’t have permission to access “LaunchAgents”.