# Building custom installer

Tags: macos, cocoa

I need to build a installer for my application which has below components/tasks -

1. Main .app file
2. Helper .app file
3. Supporting folders
4. .plist file which needs to be copied to /Library/LaunchAgents
5. load the plist file using "launchctl load"

As we see from the above components, 
1. files needs to be extracted to /Applications/ABC
2. Execute a perl command file as administrator

As step2 above involved admin activities, installer should prompt admin/local username and password. Based on this, we need to proceed with next steps.

Can someone please suggest - 
1. Installer tool (Preferably FREE) for the above scenario
2. Installer should prompt login/pwd while executing command file

Comment: Did u try using PackageMaker?

Comment: I was looking at some links where it says PackageMaker is deprecated/will be deprecated soon. Are there any other options?

Comment: you can use productbuild command from command line

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/productbuild.1.html

Comment: Are there any tutorials to build? I mean step by step doc

Comment: yeah i have included the link in my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use pkgbuild and productbuild commands to build the installer. Check this very detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487596/making-os-x-installer-packages-like-a-pro-xcode4-developer-id-mountain-lion-re)

The official documentation for these commands are here [pkgbuild](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pkgbuild.1.html) and [productbuild](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/productbuild.1.html)

There is another pkg creating app available: [iceberg](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/14516/iceberg)