# Not able to find Packagemaker

Tags: macos, xcode6, packagemaker

I am working with Xcode 6 on Mac osx 10.9.5. I need to create installer package but I am not able to find "Packagemaker". I have downloaded from "Downloads for Apple Developers" but that .dmg not contain "Packagemaker".
So can anyone have faced same problem or have found solution?

Comment: Package Maker has been deprecated as of Xcode 4.6; possible duplicate of [Making OS X Installer Packages like a Pro - Xcode4 Developer ID Mountain Lion ready pkg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487596/making-os-x-installer-packages-like-a-pro-xcode4-developer-id-mountain-lion-re)

Answer (score 0):

Packagemaker has been removed from XCode since XCode 4. It is however available inside the "**`Auxiliary Tools for XCode - Late July 2012`**" dmg which can be downloaded from Apple's developer tools downloads section [here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action).

Answer (score 0):

I have archived a copy of PackageMaker on my Github here:
https://github.com/sitting-duck/stuff/tree/master/macOSisWeird/packagemaker

In my pursuit to download PackageMaker I was unable to find it on any Apple Websites at the time of my search. (a few years ago)