# While installing package PackageKit relocate application bundle. How to disable this behaviour?

Tags: xcode, command-line, software-distribution

My program erlier distibuted as a zipped bundle, but now  I planing add daemon that must start after installation. So I decide create package while installing that will run Post-Install script.
First, I create a simple package like this:

> ```
>  productbuil --component MyAppName.app /Applications --sign "common name of my certificate" MyAppName.pkg
> ```

and trying to install it.

Installation wase successful but after I not find the app bundle in /Application directory. While inverstigatin this poltergaste I found in /var/log/install.log this line:

> installd[1954]: PackageKit: Applications/MyAppName.app relocated to Users/myUserName/PAServer/scratch-dir/UserName1.Kh-profileName/MyAppName.app

After that I find this answer [Making OS X Installer Packages like a Pro - Xcode Developer ID ready pkg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487596/making-os-x-installer-packages-like-a-pro-xcode4-developer-id-mountain-lion-re)
and try to execute command lines finded in it.

> pkgbuild --analyze --root ./MyProgram.app MyProgram.app.plist
>      pkgbuild: Inferring bundle components from contents of ./MyProgram.app
>      pkgbuild: Writing new component property list to MyProgram.app1.plist

Where I planing to edit plist file but first I was try to simple build package with default params.

> pkgbuild --root ./MyProgram.app --component-plist
>   ./MyProgram.app.plist MyProgram.pkg    pkgbuild: Reading components
>   from ./MyProgram.app.plist    pkgbuild: error: No package identifier
>   specified and not exactly one component to derive it from.

### What is wrong?

### -----------------------------

I also trying to install old version of XCode aux tools to trying use PackageMaker, but can't find documentation (I needed use PackageMaker from command line) to It even if I installing XCode 4.5.
I can't build packages manualy from GUI-tools, because into end-user bundle placed unique resource library, and manual buildin is too expensive. So i search for automatic building methods.

Answer (score 11):

You're missing the `--identifier` parameter.  Try:

```
pkgbuild --identifier MyIdentifier --root ./MyProgram.app \
--component-plist ./MyProgram.app.plist MyProgram.pkg
```

Where `--identifier MyIdentifier` is the unique name that can be registered with the system.

P.S. You may choose to follow the `suffix.domain.project` naming convention via:

```
pkgbuild --identifier com.mydomain.MyIdentifier --root ./MyProgram.app \
--component-plist ./MyProgram.app.plist MyProgram.pkg
```

Where `--identifier com.mydomain.MyIdentifier` is the unique name that can be registered with the system.