# include additional files with qt program deployment

Tags: macos, qt, dictionary, include

I have a program that when executed creates a folder in "~/Library/Application Support/MyApp" on mac. This is the directory that its config.cfg and log files and written to. The program has 2 files its depends on, a .dylib library and a .map file.

When I run macdeployqt, the .dylib is automatically copied to the Frameworks folder within the .app bundle. I have specified the file name of the .dylib in the .pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH = libokFrontPanel.dylib
DEPENDPATH = libokFrontPanel.dylib
LIBS = libokFrontPanel.dylib
```

So when building the compiler looks in the build folder for the .dylib file.

Is there a way to automatically copy the .map file from the build folder into "~/Library/Application Support/MyApp" which is where it looks for the file at run time?

I could always just have to user manually copy the file there before use, but it would be nice if it could be automated at run time/compilation time.

Thanks, Mitch

Comment: The user's Documents folder is for the user to store their documents, not for your application's config and log files. I suggest you look at the Library or Application Support folder. You can read about OS X folders in the Apple docs here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/AppRuntime/AppRuntime.html Note Table 1-1  Key directories for Mac apps

Comment: @TheDarkKnight I tried doing that but the program then requires the user to navigate to the folder where the log files are stored, Library is inaccessible through the standard file browser... Hmm

Comment: Perhaps you can think of another method for the user to select a log file, than using the standard Open File browser. If you plan on releasing your product via the App Store, I would expect the app may be declined if storing the files in the user's Documents folder.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight yes I think you right. In terms of the .map file, is there anything I can put in the .pro file to have it included in the build in the ~/Library folder?

Comment: @TheDarkKnight I have edited my original question and changed the code to use the Library/Application Support folder. It works fine to load the file from. Is there a way to have the .map file automatically copied into this directory?

Answer (score 0):

Automatically, no, but there's no reason why you can't have your application check for its existence in the user's ~/Library/ folder on startup and if it's not there, copy it with [QFile::copy](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#copy)

Alternatively, if you're distributing with a [package (pkg)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487596/making-os-x-installer-packages-like-a-pro-xcode4-developer-id-mountain-lion-re), you can create a postscript to copy the file on install.