# installation is getting failed when i click cancel of authentication page

Tags: macos, installation, pkgbuild, productbuild

[image]

I made my pkg file with pkgbuild and productbuild.
Before giving authentication details, it is going in to installation step and showing message "preparing for installation". Without giving credentials, if i click cancel My installation is getting cancelled.

[image]

Comment: That's expected behaviour if you click cancel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select 'Install', if the installation requires access to resources not belonging to the current user, the Installer's associated helper application (runner) will request an appropriate user to authenticate; usually a member of the Administrators group.

It is this helper process (runner) that is responsible for the actual installation, so if it can't obtain the user's credentials, it can't continue to install; the installation has failed and the user is notified accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Initially i made my pkg with pkgbuild alone. But later for changing welcome,background i went for productbuild. In former case when i clicked on cancel it does nothing but just stayed in installation type. It is only when i used productbuild with customised Distribution.xml installation is getting failed when i click cancel

Answer (score 0):

I found answer for this myself, We need to add auth attribute as root

pkg-ref id= auth="root"

Reference: http://macinstallers.blogspot.in/2013/01/xml-attributes-of-packagemaker.html#installation-check.
 This stackoverflow question helped me lot

[Making OS X Installer Packages like a Pro - Xcode Developer ID ready pkg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487596/making-os-x-installer-packages-like-a-pro-xcode4-developer-id-mountain-lion-re)