# How to sign APP installer on OSX using productsign?

Tags: macos, osx-gatekeeper, productsign

I got an installer certificate from Apple, my installers are custom APPs (no pkg or something). Now if I run

```
productsign —sign "Developer ID Installer: xxxx" /DATA/Install/xxx.app /DATA/Install/xxx.app.sign
```

it just says this:

```
Usage: productsign [options] --sign <identity> <input-product-path> <output-product-path>
```

I thought it is buggy or something, but maybe it just doesn't like APP files. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation states for [productsign](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/productsign.1.html):

> productsign adds a digital signature to a product archive previously created with [productbuild](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/productbuild.1.html)

So your input should not be the application bundle, but rather the archive package which you first create with [productbuild](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/productbuild.1.html).

Note that you can sign the product archive directly from productbuild with the *--sign*  option

Just to complicate things further(!), it's possible to use [pkgbuild](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pkgbuild.1.html) to create an archive and sign with that, but if I recall correctly, you must use *productbuild* if you're deploying via the App Store.

As I understand it, if your product contains multiple components, they can each be archived with *pkgbuild*, then bundled together into a single archive with *productbuild* via the use of a distribution file, which can be created with *productbuild* and the option *--synthesize*

For more detail, the top answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487596/making-os-x-installer-packages-like-a-pro-xcode-developer-id-ready-pkg) details the steps required to make a distributable package.

Comment: The problem is this is a custom crossplatform installer, so it really needs to be APP. Isn't there another way? It seems ridiculous not to allow custom apps as installers. But wouldn't be that surprising with Apple...

Comment: If it's just an app bundle, then what's wrong with [codesign](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/codesign.1.html) and a standard Developer ID certificate?

Comment: Hmm, I actually didn't try :). Apple spreads everywhere that for installers one needs to use an installer certificate, so I don't really know. I'll try.

Comment: *one needs to use an installer certificate* - Unfortunately, [few installers are signed](https://medium.com/@DubiousMind/a-sign-of-the-times-f06314ef92cf#.cbe0hxoe2)

Comment: $PACKAGEMAKER --doc $PMDOC --version $APPVERSION --out $TMPDIR$MAC${!BNAME}.pkg --scripts $SCRIPTSPATH${!BNAME}
productsign --sign "Developer ID Installer: Name" $TMPDIR$MAC${!BNAME}.pkg $BUILDDEST${!BNAME}.pkg
echo ${!BNAME} made!!