# Mac OS X Installer (pkg) and Google Analytics

Tags: macos, google-analytics, installation

I want to make installer (pkg) for my certain application on Mac OS X. I know about `pkgbuild` and `productbuild` commands and it is not problem to write simple script to make pkg. The problem is that I want to collect some information about user behaviour, when user run installer. For example, I want to know how many times users start intaller. For that purpose I deside to use `Google Analytics`, That's why my question is how can I make requests through `http` to google service? Of course, I know about `cURL`, but I don't know is this tool default in Mac OS X. Minimal version for my application is Mac OS X 10.7 Lion.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have made some things to solve my problem, but I have failed to get exactly what I want.

First off all, for send `http` requests to google service I used `curl`. On the official Apple site I not found information about is this tool default for Mac OS X, but many articals in Internet say that this tool is default for Mac OS X. My `GET` requests with `curl` look like:

```
curl --request GET 'https://ssl.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&t=event&tid=UA-...&cid=...&ec=...&ea=MacInstalled'
```

Secondly, I used `preinstall` and `postinstall` scripts for `pkgbuild` to perform `curl` commands. Very useful links on this step was:

[PackageMaker How-to](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Stuff/PackageMaker_Howto.html)

[Making OS X Installer Packages like a Pro - Xcode Developer ID ready pkg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487596/making-os-x-installer-packages-like-a-pro-xcode-developer-id-ready-pkg)

Thirdly, I made only two requests to google service: directly before installation process in `preinstall` script (MacBeginInstall) and directly after installation process in `postinstall` script (MacInstalled). The problem is that I want to make request to google service when installer start (when user see first step of installer - welcome screen). I didn't solve this problem. May be it is impossible with `pkgbuild` command.

This is my experience, maybe it will be useful for somebody :)