# Add EULA Agreement in package file of a mac app

Tags: macos, package, nwjs

I have an NWJS Mac App **hello.app**.

I signed the app using entitlements and created a package **hello.pkg** which works fine.

Now I wish to add an **EULA agreement** inside this package. Can someone suggest me how should I achieve this?

**What I tried:**

1. Generate distribution.plist or xml from hello.app

   productbuild --synthesize --product "hello.app/Contents/Info.plist" --package hello.app distribution.plist
2. Update the plist with readme/license files

   ```
           <installer-gui-script minSpecVersion="1">
                  <license file="LICENSE.html"/>
                  <readme file="README.html"/>
           </installer-gui-script>
   ```
3. Now again build to create the package.

   $ productbuild --distribution distribution.xml hello.pkg

**But I get error:**

```
Cannot copy package "hello.app" into the product. (Bundle-style package "hello.app" is not supported.)
```

Please provide suggestions.

Comment: Hi, any suggestions on this.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know `--package` must point to a `.pkg` file created by `pkgbuild`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @asr create a .pkg file using `pkgbuild` before passing it to `packagebuild`

For more info:

https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/pkgbuild/

[Making macOS Installer Packages which are Developer ID ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487596/making-macos-installer-packages-which-are-developer-id-ready)

https://medium.com/swlh/the-easiest-way-to-build-macos-installer-for-your-application-34a11dd08744