# On macOS, When adding an installer plugin to a package, an alert appears to the user when launching the package. Can it be removed somehow?

Tags: macos, cocoa, installation, info.plist

I am building a package for macOS, and I would like to include a package plugin. If I do so, even if I notarize the package, this dialog appears on launch:

[image]

Can it be somehow removed ? Thanks

Comment: macos version is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. This cannot be removed. It is a security feature to inform the user.

Instead of using a plug-in, you may be able to do what you want with [Installer JS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/installer_js) scripts.