# Add custom step to installation using pkgbuild

Tags: xcode, pkgbuild

I see that `pkgbuild` can be used to create installation files for MAC. All the examples that I see have the standard steps as shown below.

I wonder if we can add custom steps to this and execute a script during that step. Say in between "Installation" and "Summary", could I add a step called "Install Plugins" and if the user selects continue, I can run a script to download the plugins. ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

It is possible with Installer Plug-ins, but I **highly discourage** it: It seems Apple removed all documentation about it from the developer page. Not a good sign for its future. Which makes sense with the focus in recent years of locking down the system, because a Installer Plug-ins has like full system access.

The only details I find these days are in the framework header files, like *InstallerPlugins/InstallerPane.h*:

[image]

If you use Plug-ins, Install will present the user an alert with *"This package will run a program to determine if the software can be installed."* See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67138560/23028).