# How to create a macOS App Installer with Prerequisites

Tags: java, macos, installation

I'm developing a macOS app written in Swift which will not be distributed via the App Store.

I'm looking to create an installer which will install some prerequisites, more exactly install Java on the machine.

Are there any tools available that can create such an installer for an app?

Answer (score 0):

You could get use of .pkg installator, just put java inside this package and call needed setup actions in pre-install bash script. Or even use script to install brew and call brew to install java, whatever.

There is a GUI tool to make pkg-s called [Packages](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html), it works fine and it is free. There is also some documentation on their web site.

You can also create package of any complexity using only built-in, Apple-provided console [tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11487658/2869674).